# Pressing shift inserts ">"

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

In my terminal, if I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, it inserts `>`, but not every time.

In Vim, if I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, it takes the `>` as a command and moves the text to the right.

Why is my <kbd>Shift</kbd> key behaving like this?

Comment: First debugging step is probably to use either `xev` or `evtest` to see what is being generated. Do you have 2 shift keys and if so does it happen with both?

Comment: You said "... but not every time." Can you make a guess at how frequently? Are you using a wired or wireless keyboard? Have you checked if there is dirt, grime, or sticky keys causing interference?